# PHP Imagick - Animated GIF, frames per second

Tags: php, imagick, animated-gif

Into this code

```
$GIF = new Imagick();
$GIF->setFormat("gif");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_name); ++$i) {
     $frame = new Imagick();
     $frame->readImage($file_tmp[$i]);
     $frame->setImageDelay(10);
     $GIF->addImage($frame);
}

header("Content-Type: image/gif");
echo $GIF->getImagesBlob();
```

I've this part to set what I want

```
 $frame->setImageDelay(10);
```

Instead of 10, What is the correct equivalent for 24 frames per second?

[1 second / fps] >>> (1000/24) = 42 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [php documents](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedelay.php):

> The amount of time expressed in 'ticks' that the image should be
>   displayed for. For animated GIFs there are 100 ticks per second, so a
>   value of 20 would be 20/100 of a second aka 1/5th of a second.

So, 24 fps, where a second is a value of 100, would be `100/24` or 4.1.  The value must be an integer, so rounding down would be 4.  It would be more natural to do 20 frames per second which would be a delay value of 5, or 25 frames per second which would give a delay value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
// Ticks per second
   $tps = 100;
// Frames per second
   $fps = 24
   $frame->setImageDelay(ceil($tps/$fps));
```